# Laravel DOM PDF div border breaks on page split

Tags: sql, laravel, phpmyadmin, repository, dompdf

I am using dom pdf for exporting pdf file in laravel. I have been using div with border in it and div border is breaking on every page split.

This is how it look when I download my pdf. I want to close the border on every page start and end.
I use this style in dom pdf:

```css
 .page-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using dom pdf for download and i used div with border in it.My table is inside div. When i download pdf then div border is splitting on page split .My div border is not retaining on page split.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
page-break-before: always;

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am using dom pdf for downloading pdf file. I used div with table inside that div.I use border line in div and when i download pdf file then that border of div is missing on bottom of page and on the very next page top border is also missing.Now i want border in both page.Note the div was not end in single page so this problem occur.